# Dealing with log(1) in computational linguistics

Tags: statistics, logarithms

I am not sure this is the right venue for this question: if you think it is not, I will move it to another StackExchange board.

**Explanation**

I am trying to calculate phonotactic probability on a corpus of consonant-vowel-consonant (CVC) words.

Phonotactic probability can be defined as follows:

> Phonotactic probability refers to the frequency with which a
> phonological segment, such as /s/, and a sequence of phonological
> segments, such as /s^/, occur in a given position in a word ([Kansas University](https://calculator.ku.edu/phonotactic/about))

And can be calculated on segments of various length, such as monograms, bigrams, trigrams, etc. In simple terms:

> For a word like blick in English, the unigram average would include
> the probability of /b/ occurring in the first position of a word, the
> probability of /l/ in the second position, the probability of /ɪ/
> occuring in the third position, and the probability of /k/ occurring
> in the fourth position of a word. Each positional probability is
> calculated by summing the log token frequency of words containing that
> segment in that position divided by the sum of the log token frequency
> of all words that have that position in their transcription. The
> bigram average is calculated in an equivalent way, except that
> sequences of two segments and their positions are used instead of
> single segments. So for blick that would be /bl/, /lɪ/, /ɪk/ as the
> included positional probabilities

In matemathical terms, the phonotactic probability of the word *blick* would be calculated as follows:

[image]

Given an example corpus (e.g., the one from [CorpusTools documentation](https://corpustools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/phonotactic_probability.html)):

[image]

The phonotactic probability of *blick* would be calculated as follows:

[image]

**Question**

Unfortunately, in my corpus, some bigrams (e.g., /Aw/, `'Aw': [1, 1, 1, 1]`
) appear in only words with token frequency one. As such, when calculating the sum of *log()* frequencies of words starting with /Aw/, the sum ammounts to

```
log(1) + log(1) + log(1) + log(1)
```

Which in turn returns `0`. Indeed, this is not very representative, since the bigram appears in at least four words. Is there a way to deal with this from a mathematical perspective?

Comment: I think there is a related issue: if a bigram appears in first position or third position in some words in your corpus but never in second position, then perhaps you should be adding $\log(0)=-\infty$ for the second position.  This might suggest using logarithms is not completely justifiable in what claims to be a probability calculation.

Comment: The problem is more complex: because the target corpus (i.e., the one I am calculating phonotactic probability for), contains only 2 positions: first and second, or, in other terms, only the initial and final position. So, in the source corpus (i.e., that I have extracted the frequencies from), I have accounted for only bigrams in the initial/final position, even for longer words.

Comment: According to https://corpustools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/phonotactic_probability.html , "in the event that a word has a token frequency of 1, this is first replaced in the calculation with 1.00001 to avoid any problems with division by zero" .  A slightly more "principled" way  of handling the problem is to add 1 to all the observed counts, before taking their logarithms.